# call a private webservice available only in server with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm facing the following problem. I need to call a private webservice which is only available in the server where the webpage is also located.

For example: User call the website from his computer called A. The website is located in B and also the webservice is in B. When the user calles the website it should call the webservice to get a token from the webservice. But if i use

```
$.get("localhost/mywebservice.asmx/getToken")
```

it tries to find the service in clients computer A.

Is there a way to achieve it with plain javascript or jquery?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the hostname in the URL. It will then use the same hostname as the web page itself.

```
$.get("/mywebservice.asmx/getToken");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work this way because the webservice is not callable from public, but only in the server.

Comment: Then you can't call it from the browser, since the browser isn't running on the server. You need to call a public webservice, and that should call the private webservice.